# Selenium C# - Catching Javascript errors

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing with Selenium web driver using C#. I want to check my web pages that no JavaScript errors are present.

I have installed `JSErrorCollector.xpi` for Firefox and added the following lines into my code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317705/c-sharp-selenium-webdriver-javasript-errors-logging)).

```
List<object> errors = (List<object>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).executeScript("return window.JSErrorCollector_errors.pump()");
Assert.IsNull(errors);
```

But this brings up the following error:

> window.JSErrorCollector_errors is undefined (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)

Any ideas how to fix this or could anyone provide a better alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which doesn't involve JSErrorCollector.xpi - only JavaScript. You can use the JavaScriptExecuter to execute this first:

```
var errorArray = [];
window.onerror = function(message, file, line) {
    errorArray.push("message: " + message + ", file: " + file + ", line:  " + line);
};
```

And then whenever you need to get the errors, execute this JavaScript:

```
return errorArray;
```

The only drawback is, this will only capture errors which occur after you've executed this first script. But it sounds like that may be all you need based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `JSErrorCollector_errors` object in `window`, at least when you try to access its `pump` method. Make sure that when you call the `pump` function of the `JSErrorCollector_errors` object, the object already exists.

Comment: If you do this: <script>var JSErrorCollector_errors = {}; JSErrorCollector_errors.pump = function() {return "No errors"};</script> in your HTML, then you will have the object and its method created, however, this should run BEFORE you call it. In your case the error might be that you try to reach this too early.